# como puedo insertar registros en asp.net razor sin mvc?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

antes que nada soy nuevo en razor pages lo estoy aprendiendo sin mvc tengo una duda como puedo llamar a mi metodo de insertar registros desde el codigo html? al parecer me marca una expecion considerando que la tabla de mi base de datos no es identity, entonces quiero saber si hay alguna forma de poder insertar datos llamando a un metodo desde el modelo ya que aun que lo mande a llamar me marca una expecion adjunto condigo y la muestra  de la expecion. el primero es del archivo index.cshtml :

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";

}
<h1 class="display-4">Insertar</h1>
<div>
    <form method="post" asp-page-handler="InsertarRegistros">
         <label>ID</label>
        <input type="number" value="@Model.ID"/>
        <label>Producto</label>
        <input type="text" value="@Model.Producto"/>
        <label>Precio</label>
        <input type="number" value="@Model.Precio"/>
        <label>Dimensiones</label>
        <input type="text" value="@Model.Dimensiones"/>
        <label>Id_Marca</label>
        <input type="number" value="@Model.Id_MarcaProveedor"/>
        <label>Url</label>
        <input type="text" value="@Model.UrlImagen"/>
        <button>Insertar</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

este es del archivo index.cshtml.cs:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

        SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection("Server=DESKTOP-4HLG8FV;Database=Ferreteria;Trusted_Connection=True;");

        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string Producto { get; set; }

        public int  Precio { get; set; }

        public string Dimensiones { get; set; }

        public int Id_MarcaProveedor { get; set; }

        public string UrlImagen { get; set; }

        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {

        }

        public void OnPostInsertarRegistros()
        {
            conexion.Open();
            object resultado = 0;
            string QueryInsertar = @"INSERT INTO ProductosFerreteria
            (ID,Producto,Precio,Dimensiones,Id_MarcaProveedor,UrlImagen) 
            VALUES(@ID,@Producto,@Precio,@Dimensiones,@Id_MarcaProveedor,@UrlImagen)";
            SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(QueryInsertar,conexion);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Producto))
            {
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Producto", DBNull.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Producto", Producto);
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Dimensiones))
            {
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dimensiones", DBNull.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dimensiones", Dimensiones);
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(UrlImagen))
            {
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UrlImagen", DBNull.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UrlImagen", UrlImagen);
            }
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Precio", Precio);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_MarcaProveedor", Id_MarcaProveedor);
            var A = comando.ExecuteScalar();
            


        }
```

y esta es una imagen de como tengo mis registros en la tabla de mi base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta es una imagen de la expecion que me marca al intentar insertar un registro cuando doy click al boton:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ojo: mi tabla no es identity , si tengo un error o algo estoy haciendo mal favor de notificarmelo muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Porque debes retornar el objeto y tu función OnPostInsertarRegistros debe ser capaz de recibirlo

Tienes que crear una clase

```
public class Producto
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Producto { get; set; }
   public int  Precio { get; set; }
   public string Dimensiones { get; set; }
   public int Id_MarcaProveedor { get; set; }
   public string UrlImagen { get; set; }
}
```

En tu vista cambias

```
@model Producto
```

Y en el controlador

```
public void OnPostInsertarRegistros(Producto producto){
  //piezas de codigo
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(producto.Producto)) // recuerda que ahora tus variables empiezan como producto.
```

Y lo quieres o no, terminas trabajando con MVC